# Вёрстка блока с 2-мя треугольниками

Tags: css, css3, html5, scss

Доброго времени суток!
Помогите разобраться, каким образом с помощью css можно сверстать данный блок, что бы избежать вставки картинок. Поробывалось делать с помощью before, after но получился только треугольник с правой стороны.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Без картинок можно обойтись. А как насчет вставки еще пары элементов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Без вставки картинок, но с парой лишних блоков и псевдоэлементов:

```css
.d1 {
height: 300px; 
width: 300px; 
margin: 35px 20px 0 0;
background: green;
position: relative;
}

.d1:before {
content: "";
height: 0; 
width: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: -100px;
border-left: 100px solid green;
border-top: 150px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 150px solid transparent;
}

.d2 {
height: 0; 
width: 0;
background: red;
position: relative;
}

.d2:before {
content: "";
height: 0; 
width: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 280px;
border-left: 100px solid red;
border-top: 150px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 150px solid transparent;
}

.d2:after {
content: "";
height: 0; 
width: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 260px;
border-left: 100px solid green;
border-top: 150px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 150px solid transparent;
}

.d3:before {
content: "";
height: 30px; 
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 200px;
background: green;
}

.d3:after{
content: "";
height: 30px; 
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 200px;
background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
  </div>
  <div class="d3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, большое. Как раз то что нужно, красивое решение)